# Explain a simple network diagram?

Tags: networking, lan

In the image below, are bridge1, bdidge2 and bridge3 connected to each other? and how?
i tried to design this in Cisco packet tracer and i used a hub to connect the three bridges? is that right?

[image: Network Diagram]

Comment: Assuming that bridge means two port switch, then a multiport hub can be used to interconnect the bridges.  You aren't using switches, correct?

Answer (score 2):

They are obviously not *directly* connected however data can certainly move throughout LAN1/LAN2/LAN3 as they are interconnected via the bridges.

With a bridge being a scaled down switch; the communication path is based on settings. Generally speaking though yes, they can communicate with each other and are *bridging* the LAN's with each other.